# send JSON response with two method's return values

Tags: java, json, jersey

I have this method to consume JSON string I am getting here two return values.The first from the `insertData` method and it is integer `201` or `208` and the second value from `getStopRoute` it is ArrayList. How can I return the both value in Jersey with JSON in this case?

```
@Path("/data")
public class Receiver {



    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        double latD = data.getLatitude();
        double longD = data.getLongitude();

        Database db = new Database();
        int status = db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD); // return 201 or 208
        ArrayList<Integer>  route_number = db.getStopRoute(latD, longD); //return [1,9,3]

        return Response.status(status).build();

    }

}
```

JSON Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You could put them in a map and then convert to JSON with Jackson library for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please consider doing so :

**1. code**

```
     @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response storeData(Data data) {

            String macD = data.getMac();
            int routeD = data.getRoute();
            double latD = data.getLatitude();
            double longD = data.getLongitude();

            Database db = new Database();



           //inserted by jean
        SDBean bean= new SDBean();
        bean.status = db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
        bean.routes= db.getStopRoute(latD, longD); //return [1,9,3]

        return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

    }

    //inserted by jean
    public class SDBean{

          public int status;
        //@Expose 
        public ArrayList<Integer> routes;
        public String toJson(){
             //if you use jackson


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    String json =null;
    try {
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return json;

        }
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: how can I import `@Expose` ? I have this Jackson  dependency in the pom.xml file above as in the question. I cant import it when I hover over.

Comment: if you already have jackson do not use Expose and skip the 2. . @Expose annotation is part of Gson

Comment: and what is `sb` in this line `mapper.writeValueAsString(sb);` I am getting `sb cannot be resolved to a variable`?

Comment: I have added this instance to it `Receiver sb = new Receiver();` is it the right one?